# VBA Macros Lost After Updating to 2010 Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've just upgraded from Office 2007 to 2010. I had a word file with a VBA Macro in it. It think it was a .docx file. Now its become a .docm file and the VBA Macro in it is lost. I've tried all of the following:

- Try the file on another system with word 2007
- change .docm to .docx
- uninstall office 2010

But I still haven't managed to recover my word VBA macro. A lot of work had been done on this file. I would appreciate any advice on how I could get my macros back.

Comment: `It think it was a .docx`- if it was `docx` then it didn't contain any macro. so, there is no way to retrieve any code from `docx` file. Or it was another file type like `.doc`?

Comment: To be honest I don't remember the exact extension, but there was a macro in it. I was working and modifying the macro for the past month.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the answer. Apparently i was using the .docx format which saves the macro in the template. I found the macro in the old work template I was using

C:\User\UserName\AppData\Microsoft\Templates